# Extension point to refer another extension

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Lets consider an editor named 'Column Editor', where we have a number of columns. We have provided this column as an 'Extension Point', so that anybody who wants to contribute columns can add an 'Extension' to this Extension Point.

Now, We are providing sorting functionality to these columns. Whenever the editor is starting and the columns are being loaded, the column data should be sorted by a 'default column' (one of these from the contributed Columns).

First, I thought of providing an attribute to these 'Extension Points' to set whether it is the column for default sorting. But, multiple contribution provided 'true' for this attribute and it resulted in ambiguity.

Is there a value to remove this ambiguity and provide a clean solution of one default sort column?

I thought of providing another Extension Point and say which column can be the default sort column. But, this needs a reference to Extension. How can one refer another Extension in an Extension point?

Hence, I was thinking of providing another extension proint

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common for one extension point to refer to another.

For example, look at the Ant editor declaration:

```xml
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        name="%AntEditor.name"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/ant_buildfile.png"
        class="org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.editor.AntEditor"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.editor.AntEditorActionContributor"
        id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.internal.editor.AntEditor">
        <contentTypeBinding
           contentTypeId="org.eclipse.ant.core.antBuildFile"/> 
  </editor>
```

The `contentTypeBinding` element refers to the `contentTypeId` with id `org.eclipse.ant.core.antBuildFile` declared here:

```xml
<extension 
    point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> 
    <content-type  
        id="org.eclipse.ant.core.antBuildFile" 
        name="%antBuildFileContentType.name" 
        base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
        file-names="build.xml"
        file-extensions="macrodef,ent,xml,ant"
        priority="normal"> 
        <describer 
            class="org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.contentDescriber.AntBuildfileContentDescriber">
        </describer> 
    </content-type> 
</extension>
```

So the key thing is to provide a unique id for the extension. In your extension point schema you declare the id to be **required** and have type **identifier**